# The row couldn't be updated because a foreign key constraint failed. Verify the constraint and try again

Tags: magento2

```
   {
 "entity":{
  "base_currency_code":"AUD",
  "base_discount_amount":0,
  "base_grand_total":296.95,
  "base_shipping_amount":0.0,
  "base_shipping_incl_tax":5,
  "base_shipping_tax_amount":0,
  "base_shipping_discount_amount":0,
  "base_subtotal":33,
  "base_subtotal_incl_tax":33,
  "base_total_due":0,
  "base_total_paid":296.95,
  "base_to_global_rate":1,
  "base_to_order_rate":1,
  "discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,
  "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,
  "shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount":0,
  "customer_is_guest":0,
  "customer_email":"working@user.com",
  "customer_firstname":"Working",
  "customer_group_id":1,
  "customer_id":4,
  "customer_lastname":"User",
  "customer_note_notify":1,
  "discount_amount":0,
  "email_sent":1,
  "global_currency_code":"AUD",
  "grand_total":296.95,
  "order_currency_code":"AUD",
  "shipping_amount":0.0,
  "shipping_tax_amount":0,
  "shipping_description":"For this item only:",
  "shipping_discount_amount":0,
  "shipping_incl_tax":5,
  "state":"pending",
  "status":"processing",
  "store_currency_code":"AUD",
  "store_to_base_rate":0,
  "store_to_order_rate":0,
  "store_id":1,
  "subtotal":33,
  "subtotal_incl_tax":33,
  "total_due":0,
  "total_paid":296.95,
  "total_item_count":1,
  "total_qty_ordered":1,
  "tax_amount":27.0,
  "weight":1,
  "items":[
     {
        "base_original_price":99.95,
        "base_price":99.95,
        "base_price_incl_tax":109.95,
        "base_row_total":99.95,
        "name":"S00002 - [ IP1WW16ESIUPR2GRA] NEC Aspire IP1WW-16ESIU-PR2 16 Port Digital Station Card 0891014",
        "original_price":99.95,
        "price":99.95,
        "price_incl_tax":109.95,
        "product_id":11,
        "product_type":"simple",
        "qty_ordered":1.0,
        "row_total":109.95,
        "row_total_incl_tax":109.95,
        "sku":"002",
        "store_id":1,
        "weight":1
     },
     {
        "base_original_price":170.0,
        "base_price":170.0,
        "base_price_incl_tax":187.0,
        "base_row_total":170.0,
        "name":"S00002 - [ IP2WWEXIFUA1GRA] NEC IP2WW-EXIFU-A1 Programming Interface Card ",
        "original_price":170.0,
        "price":170.0,
        "price_incl_tax":187.0,
        "product_id":11,
        "product_type":"simple",
        "qty_ordered":1.0,
        "row_total":187.0,
        "row_total_incl_tax":187.0,
        "sku":"002",
        "store_id":1,
        "weight":1
     },
     {
        "base_original_price":0.0,
        "base_price":0.0,
        "base_price_incl_tax":0.0,
        "base_row_total":0.0,
        "name":"S00002 - Free delivery charges",
        "original_price":0.0,
        "price":0.0,
        "price_incl_tax":0.0,
        "product_id":11,
        "product_type":"simple",
        "qty_ordered":1.0,
        "row_total":0.0,
        "row_total_incl_tax":0.0,
        "sku":"002",
        "store_id":1,
        "weight":1
     }
  ],
  "billing_address":{
     "address_type":"billing",
     "city":"Karachi",
     "company":false,
     "country_id":"PK",
     "customer_address_id":4,
     "email":"working@user.com",
     "firstname":"Working",
     "lastname":"User",
     "postcode":"74600",
     "region":"SIN3",
     "street":[
        "abc"
     ],
     "telephone":"333333"
  },
  "payment":{
     "amount_ordered":38,
     "amount_paid":38,
     "base_amount_ordered":38,
     "base_amount_paid":38,
     "base_shipping_amount":0.0,
     "method":"banktransfer",
     "shipping_amount":0.0
  },
  "status_histories":[
     {
        "comment":"new order",
        "status":"processing"
     }
  ],
  "extension_attributes":{
     "shipping_assignments":[
        {
           "shipping":{
              "address":{
                 "address_type":"shipping",
                 "city":"Karachi",
                 "company":false,
                 "country_id":"PK",
                 "customer_address_id":4,
                 "email":"working@user.com",
                 "firstname":"Working",
                 "lastname":"User",
                 "postcode":"74600",
                 "region":"SIN3",
                 "street":[
                    "Sample Street Address"
                 ],
                 "telephone":"332543403"
              },
              "method":"freeshipping_freeshipping",
              "total":{
                 "base_shipping_amount":0.0,
                 "base_shipping_incl_tax":0.0,
                 "shipping_amount":0.0,
                 "shipping_incl_tax":0.0
              },
              "extension_attributes":[
              ]
           },
           "items":[
           ],
           "extension_attributes":[
           ]
        }
     ],
     "applied_taxes":[
     ],
     "item_applied_taxes":[
     ],
     "converting_from_quote":false
  }
```

i am hitting this end point with above parameter /V1/orders/

{
"message": "The row couldn't be updated because a foreign key constraint failed. Verify the constraint and try again."
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your order payload may be customer id issue or try developer mode then you can see error in details